# Why is it so common to see library(packages) in r but using * to load all functions in a package is bad python practice?

Tags: python, r, syntax

As someone with a background in Python coming to R, every time that I use `library(<package name>)` syntax, I feel like cutting my finger with a paper!! Because I believe anyone who has learned python as their first language knows that they shouldn't use `from <package> import *` syntax as much as possible.

- So, why most people in R community use `library()` to import everything instead of relying on `package::function` syntax which is equivalent to `package.function` in python. Aren't they thinking of their namespace?
- The fact that I see `tidyverse` complaining about namespace conflicts is evidence that R compiler doesn't have some magical intuition to understand from which package your desired function is, they why do they practice that?

Do you recommend using `library()` or `package::function` syntax in R?

Comment: As a first approximation, the only R users thinking about namespaces are package developers. The average R user is not a software developer.

Comment: Also, I would always recommend not using the tidyverse meta-package.

Comment: I also don't use tidyverse meta-package myself and import its sub-packages individually but I see people using it a lot. Even people who I know have at least more than five years of constant R experience!!

Comment: You balance convenience vs risks ... Usually, the risks are rather small in this case.

Comment: Hi @Roland. I am curious, why would you recommend not using the tidyverse meta-package? I've started using R about 2 months ago and would like to develop best practice.

Comment: @KJM If all you want to use are tidyverse functions, than sure load the meta-package. But if you want to use packages from outside that ecosystem, the risks (e.g., name collisions) can become relevant if you attach functions from such a humongous number of packages.

Comment: @Roland, oh I see. I think I will just be loading individual packages then so that (1) I avoid these potential collisions, and (2) I am thinking about which function comes from which package. Thanks for your response!